# Personalized push notification TopicLimitExceeded

Tags: push-notification, boto, amazon-sns

I want to have personalized push notification for each user in my app, for example, when someone sends a user a message, he (and only him) get a notification that someone sends him a message.

I was able to achieve this by using SNS, and create a topic for each user. However, now that I have > 100000 users, I got TopicLimitExceeded error.

Is there a way to achieve this without running into this error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of limitation you are exceeding.

Sometimes aws puts limitation on number of calls per second.

I recently ran into some trouble for downloading RDS logs. There was limit on number of calls that i can make for second

One way to solve such rate limit exceed issue is to use sleep method.

For eg:

```
sleep(5)   # sleep for 5 second
# Continue with you program execution
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: How do you know which limit you're exceeding. I didn't see other information in my log.

Comment: put try catch block and print the error message or stack trace

Comment: sorry, put try..except and print stack trace message

Answer (score 0):

I contacted AWS support and they simply increased my number of Topic limit.